# Block header broke chain ordering - Geth 1.3.5

Tags: go-ethereum

I noticed the following log entry from Geth 1.3.5:

```
queue.go:331] Header #1118680 [a94d89ec] broke chain ordering, expected 1118747
```

yet the log shows that block #1118680 was successfully downloaded earlier.

What can cause this "broke chain ordering"?  Does these mean another node was late in propogating this block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It usually means that you requested some data from a network peer, and it sent you back something completely different than what you asked for. This usually means either a badly connected peer that's having difficulties replying to your requests, or a buggy implementation sending back bad data. In either case it's just a note that someone send something bad. It shouldn't affect sync much, your node will work around the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (in `geth --testnet`), with an addition, I see the same peer sending me bad data over and over again. Could this be a malicious user? And -how- can I remove that peer? Also, why my node is only trying to connect to that peer, do I only have 1 peer?